# What does the Unicode character ^ mean in SQL for exact numerics?

Tags: sql-server-2012

What does the symbol `^` mean in SQL?

How do you read the following:

```
smallint = Integer data from –2 ^ 15 (–32,768) to 2 ^ 15–1 (32,767)
```

from the [Transact-SQL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

`^` means exponentiation there. It is a [very common meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_programming_languages), and not at all specific to SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much Cristian . so in laymen's terms what does this statement say 

smallint = Integer data from –2 ^ 15 (–32,768) to 2 ^ 15–1 (32,767).

Comment: @Alma It says that `smallint` is an integer data type with values ranging from -2 to the 15th power (which is equal to -32768) up to 2 to the 15th power minus 1 (which is equal to 32767). Note that the statement itself isn't SQL, just a description of a (T-)SQL datatype.

Comment: thank you. i am doing a self study on Database Administration Fundamentals. thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

^ usually means exponential.

IE: 2^2 = 4.  or 2^6 = 64.